# Nested Header is not working on Handsontable react component

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

I am using `@handsontable/react` component. I am not able to give a nested header for the table. I am not sure whether this plugin supports the `nestedHeader`.

This is my code,

```
 <HotTable root="hot" settings={{
          data: this.props.data,
          nestedHeaders: [
            ['Header1', { label: 'Header2', colspan: 8 }, 'C']
          ],
          rowHeaders: true,
          columns: this.getColumns(),
          colHeaders: this.getHeaders(),
          mergeCells: this.getDisplaySettings()
        }} />
```

Anyone please suggest me, how to use nestedHeader on this react-handsontable component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested headers are the feature of Handsontable PRO. You need the `@handsontable-pro/react` component.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. Thank you for the answer.